# Python, nltk: Cannot import mkdtemp

Tags: python, nltk

I got this error while trying to compile test.py that contains these two commands -

```
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
```

This is the error I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
        import nltk
    File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
        from nltk.internals import config_java
    File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 29, in <module>
        from nltk import compat
    File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py", line 206, in <module>
        from tempfile import mkdtemp
ImportError: cannot import name mkdtemp
```

The strange thing is, that these same two commands when executed on the command line work perfectly fine.

What could be the reason for this to happen? And more importantly, how do I fix this?

EDIT:

This is what i got when i executed print(sys.path)

```
['', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Anaconda2', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg']
```

EDIT2:

I realised that I had a file called tempfile.py in my working directory. Upon deletion everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `tempfile.py` somewhere in python path; which prevents import of standard library [`tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

Also make sure deleting `tempfile.pyc` if there it is.

Comment: I don't think there is. I edited my question to include the path and it doesn't contain it. What next?

Comment: The file was in my working directory, not in my path. Don't know if that's what you meant.

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu, Working directory is also included in Python path. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path